# changing the accessibility label in control center (remote command center)

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility, mpremotecommandcenter

I've got a simple app that plays a radiostation. I've added a MPRemoteCommandCenter to let the user control the audio via the control center.
Thats all working fine.

However, I want to change their accessibility labels. But this is the part where things don't work as expected.

I've set up my remoteCommandCenter as follows:

```
let remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
```

Then, I added controls and handlers:

```
remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ExternalPlaybackController.handleExternalPlayPauseCommandEvent(_:)))
```

And then, I want to add some accessibility label:

```
remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.accessibilityLabel = "Play radio"
```

This is were things don't work. If I debug the code, the compiler will execute that line. What am I making wrong?
Can you even change the accessibility labels of the remoteCommandCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you even change the accessibility labels of the remoteCommandCenter?

I never worked with this kind of component but I think that it is ignored by VoiceOver because the screen reader doesn't recognize it as an accessibility element.

In my view, your code compiles with no problems because your accessibility properties belong to the `UIAccessibility` informal protocol which means that it's well recognized as code.
However, it's not interpreted by VoiceOver as information to be read out because your element isn't a kind of a UIKit control.

I suggest to **create an [UIAccessibilityElement](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html#UIAccessibilityElement)** for your `playCommand` so as to customize its behaviour as you wish ⟹ [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility) states :

> The UIAccessibility informal protocol is also implemented by the UIAccessibilityElement class, which represents custom user interface objects. If you create a completely custom UIView subclass, you might need to create an instance of UIAccessibilityElement to represent it. In this case, you would support all the UIAccessibility properties to correctly set and return the accessibility element’s properties.

Comment: well voiceover reads the standard iOS accessibility labels in the control center, not my own one. So the elements inside control center are in fact accessibly elements (you can navigate to them), but my code does not change their labels and hints.

Comment: Even if some elements are interpreted by VoiceOver, you may not be able to change their a11y properties like the MPRemoteCommandCenter class apparently.
In this case, you could create your own custom a11y element for your command center to have a full control of the a11y properties... unless someone else finds another solution: the a11y site mentioned in my initial post is a good basis.

Comment: Found one: I can reproduce the bug if I add my code to this project: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/becoming_a_now_playable_app. If I add the line `remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.accessibilityLabel = "test"` to the file `NowPlayableCommand.swift to line 29 (inside the `.pause case), right before `remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand`

Comment: I downloaded this sample to understand your situation. I thought the command was inside your app but it's the native one whose content is controlled by you: its UI isn't up to you and you can't change anything in it, it's a blackbox with few functionalities you can't customized for a11y anyway. If you want to change anything for customizing VoiceOver in the control center, just forget it.

Comment: well, apple should then not make the remote command centers' accessibility hints public. Anyway, thanks.